# Running sml/nj on osx 10.11.3

Tags: macos, sml, osx-elcapitan, smlnj

I have a problem with SML/NJ on mac. I downloaded the right original `pgk` file. SML/NJ is installed on the right path: `/usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml` but when I try to run `sml` (command: sml) this message appears:

```
-bash: sml: command not found.
```

I think that the problem is that I have osx 10.11.3 on my mac.

Comment: This is a site for programming questions, not for basic user issues like `$PATH`.  Ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Whatever, I had this question, too, and I'm glad this person posted their question.

Answer (score 6):

You have to adjust your `PATH` variable inside `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/smlnj/bin/"
```